# "Dragon Magazine" fiction piece about two wizards who betray one another

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dungeons-and-dragons

I would like to find an old piece of fiction in *Dragon Magazine* - it's located somewhere between issues 50 - 100. I don't remember the title but the general gist goes like this:

There is a correspondence between two wizards where one ends up betraying the other through some sort of arcane magical ritual and the first wizard warns the second that his time is coming to an end because he trusted the first. The second responds that he has foreseen the first's betrayal and has not only reflected back to him his own magics but has obtained help and the first's magic is being returned to him tenfold. He suggests the first throw himself from his own tower ("... it is said that [name of tower] is high...").

Does this sound familiar to anyone? It's been driving me a little crazy - I know it's out there in *Dragon*, I am reasonably sure that it's within the range of issues above, but I can't seem to get my mind wrapped around it and was wondering if anyone else can.

(This is copy/pasted from another site where I've tried to get the info; wanted to spread the net out a little bit.)

Comment: I have the Dragon Magazine Archives, which has issues up to 200 (I think) as PDFs.  I'll check around in there.

Comment: Not having any luck.  I've focused my search on issues 1-140 (because of the way the search tool works) but not found any fiction matching your description, using the keywords you've suggested ("it is said", "tower", "reflected", tenfold"). :-(.  I've been looking at fiction articles only, not game articles.

Comment: @LAK How does one get a copy of the Dragon Magazine archive as pdf? Googling finds various people selling DVDs or CDs, but I can't find a pdf version.

Comment: @JohnRennie I bought it in the early-mid-2000s  (probably from WotC or Paizo's website, though I don't recall now).  It's a 5-CD set covering issues 1-250 (and the *The Strategic Review* newsletter that preceded *Dragon*).  I copied the files to my hard drive of course, and was extremely surprised when the application they provide for searching/indexing actually worked under Windows 10.  I probably hadn't run it since the days of XP.

Comment: @LAK we should probably take this to the chat room, but if you're interested I can explain how to convert the pdfs to plain text using [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/), and once converted to plain text you have a lot more options for searching.

Comment: @JohnRennie It actually comes with an search tool that does work pretty well, as far as I can tell.  The PDFs themselves are scanned pages, but someone somehow in 1999 built text indices on the titles and body text.  We can do the chat thing to talk more.

Comment: Ah, if they are just scans Calibre won't be able to convert them :-(

Comment: @JohnRennie On the other hand, text within them is selectable and clipboardable, but the actual PDF content is unsearchable gibberish.

Comment: I wonder if the title would help ring a bell?  (https://aeolia.net/dragondex/fiction.html) is a list of all fiction Dragon published.

Comment: archive.org also has OCRed plaintext versions of the magazine, which are poor for reading but convenient for searching; I also haven't had any luck using those search terms, though.

Comment: I have read almost all the short stories in *Dragon* from this time period, and this just doesn't sound familiar, except for the few bits of similarity to "The Blink of a Wizard's Eye."  If searching the magazine archives isn't turning anything up, I want to suggest that this story may actually have appeared elsewhere.  (The apparent memory of having read it in *Dragon* might by contamination from "The Blink of a Wizard's Eye.")

Comment: @Buzz I was thinking too that maybe it was from another magazine - *White Dwarf*, *Space Gamer*, etc.  I don't recall which others published fiction.